# context: contextMenu.SelectionContext() not working for selected text in input fields

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My little project - extension for Firefox that translate text. User select text on page, make right click and see translation right in the context-menu or in popup. In my `contextMenu.Item` I am using `context: contextMenu.SelectionContext()` for determin context (for example, user click on image or on selected text).

But this not working if text selected in input field, [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) not mentioned it. What I need to do for handling selection context for **input fields**, not only for regular text on page? In this situation I see my context-menu, but in debug I see that selected text was not send to the code of my extension.

I tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302480/force-context-menu-to-appear-for-form-inputs) - nothing.

[image]

My current code is:

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
var uuid = require('sdk/util/uuid').uuid();
var uuidstr = uuid.number.substring(1, 37);
var notifications = require("sdk/notifications");
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var self = require('sdk/self');
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var prefs = require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs;
var cmitems = null;

var wasTranslatedSecondTime = false;
var inProgress = '...';
var translated = '';

var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    data: uuidstr, // for 'binding' tooltop's 'id' + text
    label: inProgress, // ...
    image: self.data.url('ico.png'),
    context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
    contentScript: 'self.on("context", function() {' +
                        'var selectionText = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                        'self.postMessage({name:"context", data:selectionText});' +
                        'return true;' +
                    '});' +
                    'self.on("click", function() {' +
                        'var selectionText = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                        'self.postMessage({name:"click", data:"https://translate.yandex.ru?text=" + selectionText.replace("&", "%26")});' +
                    '})',
    onMessage: function(message) {
        if (message.name == 'context') {
            menuItem.label = inProgress; // ...
            if (cmitems != undefined) cmitems[0].tooltipText = '';
            var input = message.data.replace('&', '%26');
            translate('ru', input); // default direction - from EN to RU
        } else { // if (message.name == 'click')
            tabs.open(message.data);
        }
    }
});

function translate(lang, input) {
    Request({ // key is not referral but API-key: https://api.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/concepts/api-overview.xml
        url: 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20150627T071448Z.117dacaac1e63b79.6b1b4bb84635161fcd400dace9fb2220d6f344ef&lang=' +
                                                                                    lang + '&text=' + input,
        onComplete: function (response) {
            translated = response.json.text[0];
            if (input == translated && wasTranslatedSecondTime == false) {  // if input on Russian and we receive the same text -
                translate('en', input);                                     // translate again selected text into English
                wasTranslatedSecondTime = true;
            } else { // show results
                if (prefs.popup) popup(translated);
                menuItem.label = translated;
                wasTranslatedSecondTime = false;
                if (prefs.tooltip) tooltip(translated);
            }
        }
    }).get();
}

function popup(text) {
    if (text.length > 0)
        notifications.notify({
            title: 'translate.yandex.ru',
            text: text,
            time: 5000
        })
}

function tooltip(translated) {
    menuItem.data = uuidstr + translated;
    cmitems = getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document.querySelectorAll(".addon-context-menu-item[value^='"+uuidstr+"']");
    cmitems[0].tooltipText = cmitems[0].value.substring(36);
}
```

Comment: Its a limitiation of the sdk context menu in that it wont show if you right click in editable fields. This is what i remember from playing with it a couple years ago, things might have changed. The way to work around this is to not use the sdk. But I would recommend you wait for a more recent sdk dev to reply/comment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your question boils down to: How do I get the selected text, even when it is in an input field?

You are currently using `var selectionText = window.getSelection().toString();` which is failing when the selected text is in an input field.

In one of my extensions, I use the following to obtain the selected text.  It works even when the selected text is in an input field:

```
/**
 * Fix an issue with Firefox that it does not return the text from a selection if 
 * the selected text is in an INPUT/textbox.
 */
function getSelectedText(win,doc) {
    //Adapted from a post by jscher2000 at:
    //  http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=2268557
    //Is supposed to solve the issue of Firefox not getting the text of a selection when
    // it is in a textarea/input/textbox.
    var ta;
    if (win.getSelection && doc.activeElement){
        if (doc.activeElement.nodeName == "TEXTAREA" ||
                (doc.activeElement.nodeName == "INPUT" &&
                doc.activeElement.getAttribute("type").toLowerCase() == "text")
        ){
            ta = doc.activeElement;
            return ta.value.substring(ta.selectionStart, ta.selectionEnd);
        } else {
            //As of Firefox 31.0 this appears to have changed, again.
            //Try multiple methods to cover bases with different versions of Firefox.
            let returnValue = "";
            if (typeof win.getSelection === "function"){
                returnValue = win.getSelection().toString();
                if(typeof returnValue === "string" && returnValue.length >0) {
                    return returnValue
                }
            } //else
            if (typeof doc.getSelection === "function"){
                returnValue = doc.getSelection().toString();
                if(typeof returnValue === "string" && returnValue.length >0) {
                    return returnValue
                }
            } //else
            if (typeof win.content.getSelection === "function"){
                returnValue = win.content.getSelection().toString();
                if(typeof returnValue === "string" && returnValue.length >0) {
                    return returnValue
                }
            } //else
            //It appears we did not find any selected text.
            return "";
        }
    } else {
        return doc.getSelection().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added your function, but now I have error in console that `getSelectionText is not defined`. My code is here https://github.com/vitaly-zdanevich/extension-firefox-yandex-translate/blob/master/lib/main.js

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich, Ah, OK. You meant that it said `getSelectedText` is not defined (not getSelectionText). That is because the function needs to be part of your content script. As it is currently in your code, you have it defined in your main code, not your content script.  The content script runs in a completely separate context and can not see anything that is in the main script.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich, Note: there was an error made when I copied the code: the second inner `if` statement/block should have contained `doc.getSelection`, not `win.getSelection`. This has been corrected above

Comment: Thank you, next error is: `doc.activeElement.getAttribute(...) is null`, this is about line `doc.activeElement.getAttribute("type").toLowerCase() == "text")`. You have some ideas about this? Updated code still at https://github.com/vitaly-zdanevich/extension-firefox-yandex-translate/blob/master/lib/main.js + https://github.com/vitaly-zdanevich/extension-firefox-yandex-translate/blob/master/data/script.js. Oh, I see, this is because I select `input` without `type=text` at ya.ru...

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich, Interesting, I do not see that error when I use the code, but mine is in a different environment (bootstrapped add-on main code, not a content script). Could you give me a pointer to the web page on which you tested, and the input field you are using so I can duplicate the issue here?

Comment: Maybe you know - how can I replace selected text? I need send node from script.js to main.js?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich, I would suggest you [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to get input from multiple people, and so it can be found by others who might want to know. However, while you can pass information back and forth from the content script to your main script, manipulating the DOM to change the text will need to happen in the content script.